# nodejs installation error in ubuntu

Tags: apt, node.js, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to install nodejs on a newly built Ubuntu VM(Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS), but getting the below error.

```
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_16.19.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (16.19.1-deb-1nodesource1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_16.19.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/node/common.gypi', which is also in package libnode-dev 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_16.19.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Commands I used -

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -

apt install nodejs
```

Running from root user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a conflict between the `Node.js` package you want to install and the `libnode-dev` that is already on your computer.

Here is how to solve this problem: first remove the problematic package `sudo apt-get remove libnode-dev` then update all your packages `sudo apt-get update` then install `Node.js` the same way you did before

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Now your `Node.js` should be working properly